# Get a cell value from a row based on another cell value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

i want to get the age of a particular name ,lets say i want to get the age of Garrett Winters , using jquery . the record can be at any row of the table.i have to search the whole table and get the corresponding age in a variable..

**i want to search the column *Name* for a particular value and get the corresponding age**

```
<table id="table1" border="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>CNF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>CNF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>CNF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>TMP</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>CNF</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>TMP</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

i m new to jquery .Help me out

Comment: Atleast show the HTML structure.

Comment: Table structure is nice but we want the HTML Structure

Comment: attaced html structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this. It works for me. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x2g12180/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var nameToSearch ="Tiger Nixon";
   $('table tr').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('td').eq(0).text() == nameToSearch)
            alert("Age of "+nameToSearch+" is "+$(this).find('td').eq(3).text());         
   });
});
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `:contains` Psudeo selector in jquery. Get the **age** of the '**Garrett Winters**'

```
var serachName = 'Garrett Winters';
$("table tbody tr td:contains("+serachName+")").parent().find('td:eq(3)').text()
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/x2g12180/4/)